# Show android date without time

Tags: android, date

Is there a reliable way I can get the current date without time regardless of locale?
If I use `.toGMTString()` I get it in this format : `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy`

I need it to work regardless of country so in the **UK** it would be `DD/MM/YYYY` but in the us `MM/DD/YYYY`

I'm sure there must be a really easy way to do this but can I find it?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SimpleDateFormat`. Code sample.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd yyyy"); 
sdf.format(new Date());
```

This would return Thu Aug 25 2011 for today's date.

Answer (score 3):

There is a special helper class for this in android: [`android.text.format.DateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html). It has a static public method called [`getDateFormat()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getDateFormat%28android.content.Context%29) which returns locale aware and user-setttings aware date formatter.

You can use it to format the date only part:

```
String formattedDate = DateFormat.getDateFormat(mContext).format(new Date());
```

Comment: this is the most correct - Shafi's answer is not localizable and forces American style date system on everyone.

Answer (score 1):

```
myString = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(myDate);
```

Comment: thanks, that was exactly what i was looking for without creating any unhandy sdf...